# node.js testing if event was emitted using sinon.js without the use of timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I've tried to figure out how could I test with sinon.js when an event which is emitted asynchronously have emitted ?

So far what I'm doing is setting a timeout in which I know the event will be surly emitted, but that's ugly and could add up to the total time of tests run and I don't wanna do it:

```
it('check that event was called', function(done) {
    ...
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var cbSpy = sinon.spy();
    obj.on('event', spy);
    obj.func(cbSpy); // emits event 'event' asynchronously and calls cbSpy after it was emitted
    setTimeout(function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy, 'event "event" should be emitted once');
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(cbSpy, 'func() callback should be called once'); // won't work since the callback will be called only after the event has been emitted and all event listeners finished
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a stab at this but without using Sinon (there's really no need for it here).

```
it('check that event was called', function(done) {
    var callbackCalled = false;
    var eventCalled = false;

    var checkIfDone() {
      if (callbackCalled && eventCalled) {
        done();
      }
    }

    var callbackSpy = function () {
      callbackCalled = true;
      checkIfDone();
    }

    var eventSpy = function () {
      // Spy was called.
      // Add assertions for the arguments that are passed if you want.
      eventCalled = true;
      checkIfDone();
    };

    obj.on('event', eventSpy);
    // emits event 'event' and invokes callback after it was emitted
    obj.func(callbackSpy); 
});
```

What might be better is just test one thing at a time.

```
it('should emit `event`', function(done) {
    var callback = function () {}

    var eventSpy = function () {
      // Spy was called.
      // Add assertions for the arguments that are passed if you want.
      done()        
    };

    obj.on('event', eventSpy);
    // emits event 'event' and invokes callback after it was emitted
    obj.func(callback); 
});

it('should invoke the callback', function(done) {
    var callback = function () {
      // Callback was called.
      // Add assertions for the arguments that are passed if you want.
      done()        
    }

    obj.func(callback); 
});
```

In either case, the test will be done when the async processes are finished. I'd use the second example because it means you can focus on one thing at a time and the test code is much cleaner.